# Translation in symfony form event

Tags: php, symfony

In a custom formType I have an evenListener

```
$builder->add('somefield');
....
//surveyor and surveyorid can't be empty
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $data = $event->getData();
    if($data['surveyor']=='' && $data['surveyorid']==''){
    form = $event->getForm();
    $form->addError(new \Symfony\Component\Form\FormError('esto.esta.mal'));
}
});
```

The first argument of FormError() is "The translated error message", so,
if If I don't like to pass the translator as argument to the formType and I can't get the translator in my formType. How can I translate this custom error?

My intermediate solution is to translate all form errors and pass them as options to the form. This is a sort example:

In controller:

```
....
editAction(Request $request)
{ 

//translate errors 
$errors = [
'form.emptynotallow'=>$this->get('translator')->trans('form.emptynotallow', [], 'somedomain'),
'form.multiplenotallow'=>$this->get('translator')->trans('form.multiplenotallow', [], 'somedomain'),    
];

//
$form = $this->createForm( $formType, $entity, ['errors'=>$errors]);

....
if ($form->isValid()) {
...
}else{errors to string
return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse(['e'=>(string) $form->getErrors(true, false)]);
}
....
```

In formType, something like:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $defaults)
{
    $errors = $defaults['errors'];//translated errors
....

     $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use ($errors) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        if($data['surveyor']=='' && $data['surveyorid']==''){
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $form->addError(new \Symfony\Component\Form\FormError( sprintf($errors['form.emptynotallow'] )));//translated message
        }
        if($data['surveyor']!=='' && $data['surveyorid']!==''){
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $form->addError(new \Symfony\Component\Form\FormError($errors['form.multiplenotallow']));//translated message
        }              
     });    
....

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Gpt\MyBundle\Entity\Mapsurveyor',
        'errors'=>array()
        ));
         
}
```

I would rather a more elegant solution

Any help will be appreciated

**EDIT**
Multiple options with Custom validators.yml o default validator symfony messages.

- Constraint callback function in formType

  ```
    class SurveyorType extends AbstractType
    {

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    ...
    }

    /**
     * Constraints
     *
     * @param Mapsurveyor $entity
     * @param ExecutionContextInterface $context
     */
    public function isValid(Mapsurveyor $entity, ExecutionContextInterface $context): void
    {
    if($entity->getSurveyor()===null && $entity->getSurveyorid()===null){//not blank
        $context->buildViolation('form.emptynotallow')//Custom validators.yml message
            ->setParameter('code', 100)
            ->addViolation();
    }
    if ($entity->getSurveyor()!=null && $entity->getSurveyorid()!=null){
        $context->buildViolation('form.multiplenotallow')//Custom validators.yml message
            ->setParameter('code', 100)
            ->addViolation();
    }
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
    $resolver->setDefaults(['attr'=> ['id'=>'surveyorMapForm'],
        'constraints'=>[
            new Callback([$this, 'isValid'])
        ]]);
   }
  ```

-- Valdation in entity: loadValidatorMetadata https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html

```
class Mapsurveyor
{

...

    /**
     * Check for duplicate ID/text in a ManyToOne relationship
     * @param ClassMetadata $metadata
     * @return void
     */
    public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
    {
    $metadata->addConstraint(new UniqueEntity([
        'fields' => ['map', 'surveyorid'],
        'errorPath' => 'surveyorid',
        'message' => 'This value is already used.',
    ]))->addConstraint(new UniqueEntity([
            'fields' => ['map', 'surveyor'],
            'errorPath' => 'surveyor',
            'message' => 'This value is already used.',//default symfony message
        ])
    );
    }
```

-- Valdation in entity:  @Assert https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html

```
class Mapsurveyor
{

...

    /**
     * Must fill ID or text. Custom validators.yml message
     * @Assert\IsFalse(message = "form.emptynotallow")
     */
    public function hasBlankFields(): bool
    {
    return (is_null($this->surveyor) && is_null($this->surveyorid));
    }

    /**
     * Use ID or text field, not both. Custom validators.yml message
     * @Assert\IsFalse(message = "form.multiplenotallow")
     */
    public function hasTooManyFields(): bool
    {
    return (!is_null($this->surveyor) && !is_null($this->surveyorid));
    }
```

-- Autowire is also available in constructor formTypes

```
class MyformType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @var TranslatorInterface 
     */
    private $translator;
    
    public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        $this->translator= $translator;      
    }
```

Comment: same problem here... I asked a new question on SO a few hours ago but since nobody could answer yours, I have little hope. I'm thinking of injecting the translator service into the form, but it won't be much more elegant than your solution.

Comment: I ended up using Translator as parameter, the previous solution is difficult to maintain updated.